# Titlecase in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to convert data that is in a `textbox` the strings would be like this:

```
maureen o'hara -> Maureen O'Hara
maureen macnamee -> Maureen MacNamee
Maureen mctavis ->Maureen McTavis
```

What is the best way to got about this?

Thanks

**EDIT 1:**
What i have tried:

```
Name = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(AccountName.ToLower());
```

Comment: The best approach that I know of is CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase but it doesn't convert the inner characters in their uppercase. It seems to be to broad to be generalized also for a specific culture

Comment: There isn't anyway that you'll be able to do this since you won't ever be able to distinguish between names that need a capital letter in the middle and those that don't .. For example, "MacNamee" and "Macanelli".

Comment: There isn't a direct way to do it, however you could use a combination of textinfo.titlecase and a custom algorithm/regex to detect certain naming conventions (like Mac/Mc, hyphenated names and alike) splitting into let's say a char array and taking the appropriate steps to capitalize from there. Just my two cents.

Comment: @Gabe, Thanks how could i use a regex?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: There are several ways you could approach it. I'll see if I can come up with something really quick, but it'll be dirty and fast

Comment: @AndroidAL - http://pastebin.com/4ba9jxsj this is what I made for you, was going to post it as Jamie posted. Although the obvious answer at this point is clear, this shows a way in which you can do it yourself. Took me about 5-10 mins to throw together. Works just fine. Figured I'd post it anyway, took the time to do it and it's working code lol.

Comment: @Gabe, Many Thanks for that. Could you post is as an answer when you get a chance?, it would help others.Thanks Again

Comment: @AndroidAL Topics been marked as duplicate so no more posting answers (despite the 'duplicate' not being correct), but that code is ugly, likely to have bugs and just dirty. Only reason I did it was for illustrative purposes to show it _can_ be done, not this is the _way_ to do it. Nevertheless, for this purpose on a two worded name, it skips the first name goes to the second and processes it based on conventions added. Add an extra word to the name or something and it'll likely break lol

Answer (score 2):

This answers your current question but it might also be good for any other work you are currently doing.

There is a libary called [`Humanizer`](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer) that will do all of this for you and more.

This is what you would need to do once you have referenced the libary:

```
"maureen o'hara".Transform(To.TitleCase) //returns "Maureen O'Hara"
```

Comment: Didn't know about this - Thanks.

Comment: @Gabe it's quite a useful tool. It does quite a lot and it's pretty good for presenting data to the user. The `DateTime` implementations are quite useful too.

Comment: So it seems, just went over the code base and it looks really impressive. Going to save me a lot of time. Really - thanks for the share.